# Problem in solving a logical Equivalence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Prove or disprove the following equivalence: 
$$ ∀x Px \wedge ∀x Qx \Leftrightarrow ∀x ∃y ( Px \vee Qy ) $$

I've tried it, but I do not know how to solve logical equivalences involving quantifiers.

Comment: Have you understood what each of the two sides means? Does it feel intuitively likely that they're equivalent?

Comment: Yes. And they do not seem to be equal. But I want a rather mathematical proof.

Comment: x @user: Okay. If you want to prove that two wffs are _not_ equivalent, the standard technique is to construct an interpretation in which one is true and the other is false, or vice versa. That ought to be pretty simple here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1) Some Background**

First let us recall some well-known equivalences:

> (i) $\vDash ∀x(ϕ ∧ ψ) ↔ ∀xϕ ∧ ∀xψ$
>
> (ii) $\vDash ∃x(ϕ ∨ ψ) ↔ ∃xϕ ∨ ∃xψ$

Since ∀ and ∃ are generalizations of ∧ and ∨ respectively, we observe that (i) and (ii) simply states that ∀ (∃) can be distributed over ∧ (∨). The same holds for their respective distribution over ∨ and ∧, but only if the condition below is met:

> (iii) $\vDash ∀x(ϕ ∨ ψ) ↔ ∀xϕ ∨ ψ$, if $x \notin FV(ψ)$
>
> (iv) $\vDash ∃x(ϕ ∧ ψ) ↔ ∃xϕ ∧ ψ$, if $x \notin FV(ψ)$

And finally:

> (v) $\vDash \forall xϕ ↔ ϕ$, if $x \notin FV(ϕ)$
>
> (vi) $\vDash ∃xϕ ↔ ϕ$, if $x \notin FV(ϕ)$

which simply means that a superfluous quantification can always be eliminated.

---

**(2) The Answer**

After considering those equivalences shown above, we can start by noticing that

\begin{align} ∀x Px \wedge ∀x Qx & \Leftrightarrow ∀x ∃y ( Px \vee Qy ) \tag{1}\\
& \Leftrightarrow ∀x (∃yPx \vee ∃yQy ) \tag{2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow ∀x (Px \vee ∃yQy ) \tag{3}\\
&\Leftrightarrow ∀x Px \vee ∃yQy \tag{4}\\
\end{align}

(that is, in (1) we apply (ii); in (2) we apply (vi); since $x \notin FV(∃yQy)$ we use (iii) in (3) and we obtain (4).)

Hence our original equivalence means that

> $∀x Px \wedge ∀x Qx \Leftrightarrow ∀x Px \vee ∃yQy$

Now isn't easier to construct an interpretation where this does not hold?

- Let $M \vDash ∀x Px$: isn't possible that $M \vDash ∃yQy$ but not $M \vDash ∀x Qx$?

Can you work on the details?